# With SQL, how do remove a day from a date value if it falls on a certain day?

Tags: sql, date, case

I am having an issue removing a day from a column if it falls on a specific day.

How do I remove a day if the date value falls on '2/29/2024'? I need to remove it from ANY year that date occurs so it will be on 2/28.

I tried this and it still leaves the date as 2/29/2024:

```
   CASE WHEN UOS.ExpirationDate LIKE '2/29%' THEN
   convert(char(10), DATEADD(day, -1, UOS.ExpirationDate), 101) 
   ELSE convert( char(10), UOS.ExpirationDate, 101 ) END as ExpirationDate
```

When I hardcode it like this, it gives me '2/28/2024':

```
   CASE WHEN UOS.ExpirationDate = '2/29/2024' THEN
   convert(char(10), DATEADD(day, -1, UOS.ExpirationDate), 101) 
   ELSE convert( char(10), UOS.ExpirationDate, 101 ) END as ExpirationDate
```

I need for it to subtract a day from 2/29 regardless of the year.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used above.)

Comment: Column UOS.ExpirationDate data type?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Please use ISO format for dates in the form `2024-02-29` instead of `2/29/2024`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many SQL implementations have a way to extract specific parts of a date (such as `month(date)` or `day(date)` functions).

Once you figure out what these functions are in your dbms, you could do the following:

```
CASE WHEN month(UOS.ExpirationDate) = 2 AND day(UOS.ExpirationDate) = 29 THEN
convert(char(10), DATEADD(day, -1, UOS.ExpirationDate), 101) 
ELSE convert( char(10), UOS.ExpirationDate, 101 ) END as ExpirationDate
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it! I'm not sure why I got voted down but OH WELL! I got my answer thanks! lol

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using T-SQL.

Convert to `varchar(4)` will extract only month and the day part :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN UOS.ExpirationDate LIKE '2/29%' THEN
     CONVERT( varchar(4), DATEADD(day, -1, UOS.ExpirationDate), 101) 
ELSE CONVERT( char(10), UOS.ExpirationDate, 101 ) END as ExpirationDate
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AkfTCEvq)